# integral over almost sure existing derivatives

Tags: calculus, probability, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ and $g$ and $f-g$ be real-valued, Lipschitz functions, with Lipschitz constant smaller or equal to 1, on $[a,b]$ whose derivatives are positive and exist only $\lambda$-almost surely. Does then the following hold:
\begin{align*}
\int_r^t|\frac{d}{dx}f(x)-\frac{d}{dx}g(x)|dx \leq t-r
\end{align*}
I was thinking of
\begin{align}
\int_r^t|\frac{d}{dx}f(x)-\frac{d}{dx}g(x)|dx =\int_A\frac{d}{dx}f(x)-\frac{d}{dx}g(x)dx +\int_B\frac{d}{dx}g(x)-\frac{d}{dx}f(x)dx
\end{align}
with $A=\{x:\frac{d}{dx}f(x)-\frac{d}{dx}g(x)\geq 0\}$ and $B=A^c$, but I am confused about the almost sure existence of the derivatives.

Comment: Almost sure existence just means you must ignore the part of the domain of the integral on which either derivative fails to exist. Since this region is of measure zero, there's no problem. While I'm commenting, the problem statement isn't quite true: consider $f=2x,g=0$. Then the desired integral evaluates to $2(t-r)$.

Comment: sorry, by Lipschitz I meant with Lipschitz constant $\leq 1$ so $2x$ is not in the game.

Comment: Even then, take $f=x$ and $g=-x$. I guess you want $f-g$ to have Lipschitz constant no more than 1.

Comment: exactly, thanks.

Comment: when $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}g(x)$ are Riemann integrable, then I could estimate the first summand in my equation by $\int_r^t \mathbb{I}_A (\frac{d}{dx}f(x)-\frac{d}{dx}g(x))dx\leq\lambda(A)(f(t)-g(t)-f(r)+g(r))$, correct? Does the same hold when only Lebesgue integrability is assumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of $f-g$ are almost surely bounded by your Lipschitz constant (the so called essential supremum). Then you can use the usual supremums norm estimate for the integral, that is,
$$ \int_A f d \lambda = esssup|f| \cdot \lambda(A).$$
This holds in fact for every positive measure.